# What test is appropriate to analyse this data?

Tags: repeated-measures, crossover-study

In a crossover- trial:

Outcome: continuous: cholesterol level

Factor 1: categorical: two levels: within subject repeated measure [treatment A (standard) and treatment B (new)]. So same subject received randomly A and B or B and A treatment in two sessions after considering a washout period.

Factor 2: categorical: two levels:  between subject measure (smoker/non-smoker)

Covariates: age, sex, race, bmi

If I want to see:

Whether there is any difference between smoker and non-smokers in terms of cholesterol reduction in response to new treatment compared to standard treatment?

N = 30 (for now, it will increase to 90 at the end of study)

Comment: Do you have baseline cholesterol of your participants prior to any treatment?